# Difficulties compiling netfilter_queue for in CentOS 5.4 (GCC error)

Tags: c, linux, gcc, centos, netfilter

I'm seriously discouraged after spending hours on trying to figure out what are my problems while compiling a c library (netfilter_queue) for my centos 5.4 machine.
I am running centos **x64** machine.

When running ./configure I saw an error indicating that my compiler has failed.
After inspecting my "config.log" file, created by the ./configure command I saw that it failed compiling a sanity c file (probably used to check whether my compiler works correctly)

It failed with the errors:

```
/tmp/iuucsLU.s: Error: Suffix or operands invalid for `push`
/tmp/iuucsLU.s: Error: Suffix or operands invalid for `push`
/tmp/iuucsLU.s: Error: Suffix or operands invalid for `pop`
/tmp/iuucsLU.s: Error: Suffix or operands invalid for `pop`
/tmp/iuucsLU.s: Error: Suffix or operands invalid for `pop`
/tmp/iuucsLU.s: Error: Suffix or operands invalid for `push`
```

When I figured out that my problem is probably the gcc I created the following c file:

```
#import <stdio.h>
main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

I named the file 'test.c' and tried to compile it using "gcc test.c" and it failed with the same errors.
I figured out that my problems are probably 32/64 bit compatibility problems so I tried running it specifying a specific assembler.

1. When I executed "gcc -m32 test.c" it failed with the same errors.
2. When I executed "gcc -m64 test.c" it failed with the following error:

   test.c:0: sorry, unimplemented: 64-bit mode not compiled in

I can't figure out what my problem is, I am **surely** running a 64-bit machine.
Just to note, I installed gcc and all its dependencies manually using rpm supplying the rpm files from the CentOS-CD.

Help will be greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance, Lauren.

Comment: Why did you install them manually with `rpm` instead of using `yum`? What does `uname -a` say? What does `rpm -qa --qf '%{n}-%{v}-%{r}.%{arch}\n' gcc` say?

Comment: Because my machine is actually emulated with virtualbox and not connected to the internet and therefore not connected to the online repository. I could use c6-media repository but I preferred installing it on my own

Comment: `c6-media` or `c5-media`? What about the output from those other commands?

Comment: Actually c5, my mistake. What do you mean by "other commands"? which commands would you like to get the output of?

Comment: The two I mentioned in my first comment.

Comment: uname -a: uname -a = Linux 2.6.18-348.3.1.el5 #1 SMP Mon Nov 17 13:39:25 EDT 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: You actually led me to the solution, thank you very much!. the problem wat I was using 64 bit machine but I installed 32 bit only gcc and my default assembler was 32 bit which confused my compiler. the problem can be solved by downloading the specific RPMs (ironicly the cd provides only 32 bit RPMs what makes nonsense). thank you Etan!

Comment: You should post the solution as an answer to this question and accept it if you think it will be useful for someone in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem wat I was using 64 bit machine but I installed 32 bit only gcc and my default assembler was 32 bit which confused my compiler. the problem can be solved by downloading the specific RPMs (ironicly the cd provides only 32 bit RPMs what makes nonsense). thank you Etan!